# Nodejs NTLM/Basic auth in SOAP

Tags: node.js, web-services, soap, ntlm

I try to connect nodeJs with soap service, using [SOAP](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap) package.

In server I have a basic authentification.

How I can put basic authentification in soap library? I have this code:

```
  soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {

     console.log(err)

  });
```

in the log err, I receive the 401 page (for not auth). In web page of SOAP package I see this method:

client.setSecurity(new soap.BasicAuthSecurity('user', 'pass'));

Where I need to put this code? the reicevied client inside createClient are undefined.

**EXTRA:** The ideal was I can auth using NTLM, it's posible? I have a node app inside the same machine than soap server.

**EDIT**
I try to set NTLM credentials with soap-ntlm-2 library, using this code:

```
 var url = "http://server/instance/ReportService2010.asmx";
var options = {
    wsdl_options: {
        ntlm: true,
        username: "RSUser",
        password: "Reporting2012",
        workstation: "",
        domain: ""
    }
};

soap.createClient(url, options, function (err, client, body) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    // normal use 
    //client.setSecurity(new soap.NtlmSecurity(options.wsdl_options.userName, options.wsdl_options.password, options.wsdl_options.domain, options.wsdl_options.workstation)); 
    // or object can be passed 
    client.setSecurity(new soap.NtlmSecurity(options.wsdl_options));

    console.log(client.describe());
    report = client.ReportingService2010.ReportingService2010Soap;
});
```

But I have the same error massage: client is undefined.